# Uninstall unused dependencies via bower

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have created an AngularJS application utilising the [SB Admin 2](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) layout. I installed it via Bower, which also installed a lot of  dependencies such as Flot.js and others. My question is, I don't use any of this extra libraries, how can I remove this unnecessary libraries?

Comment: just because you use angularjs with this template doesn't automatically make the question about angularjs.  the angularjs tag feels irrelevant here, as this is really about managing a UI template, which angular isn't responsible for.

Answer (score 2):

command to uninstall a bower package

```
bower uninstall library-name
```

use --save to remove the same as a dependency from bower.json

```
bower uninstall library-name --save
```

Before uninstalling, Make sure that you have removed the respective module as a dependency in your angular application.

Comment: However, these dependencies are not listed in the bower.json file. I saw these dependencies via the command `bower list`